# Making a controller work from the non-standard directory in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm creating a base code that will ultimately work for multiple sites. I managed to easily split it to support multiple "view" folders but I'm not sure how to do the same for controllers. This is the general structure:

```
/app/Http/Controllers     <--- standard controller folder
/resources/view           <--- standard view folders
```

This is the structure I want:

```
/sites/ASITE/view         <--- this I got working
/sites/ASITE/Controllers  <--- this I don't know how to get working
```

If I create a controller in /app/Http/Controllers and I create a route:

```
Route::get('/test', '\App\Http\Controllers\TestController@test')->name('Test');
```

Then it works fine if I call /test. But If I move it to "/sites/ASITE/Controllers" and change the namespace to:

```
sites\ASITE\Controllers;
```

And make the route:

```
Route::get('/test', '\sites\ASITE\TestController@test')->name('Test');
```

Then I get error "Target class [sites\ASITE\TestController] does not exist."

Any thoughts on how to get a controller to work from another folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\App\Http\Controllers\TestController` is not telling Laravel that `TestController.php` exists in `App/Http/Controllers`. It's saying that the `TestController` class is in the namespace `App\Http\Controllers`.

You'll have a line like this in `TestController.php`:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

If you want to change the namespace, you'll need to do it there:

```php
namespace sites\ASITE;
```

The reason the `App` namespace is available, and the `sites` namespace is not, is that you haven't defined the `sites` namespace in your `composer.json`:

```json
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "sites\\": "sites/" <<< Add this line here
    }
},
```

Comment: Dang that might be it! Will be trying it in a bit! Thanks!